# Android launching music player using intent

Tags: android

Is it possible to open the music app from my app in android, or is it best to write a whole new music app inside of mine. I would rather use theirs since the user will already be comfortable with it.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I found one way to do this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(YOUR_SONG_PATH), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How to check the media player is app is availbe or not on the device

Comment: This doesn't work on the Nexus 6 (opens in photos app)

Comment: @nbarraille try audio/mp3 instean of audio/*

Comment: When I try this Android Studio says `startActivity()` wants a context instead of an intent. My `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are 28.

Comment: For me I needed to use `startActivity(getContext(), intent, null)`. Now it's working like a charm! Thanks!! I'm doing this from inside an adapter if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Dan i dont see such method startActivity(getContext(), intent, null) exists

Comment: You need to add `intent.resolveActivity(CONTEX.getPackageManager())` in `if` statement to make sure the app won't crash if no app can't handle the request.

Answer (score 23):

To simply launch the music player do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: plz will you tell me what all things should be done after writing the above code of yours.your help will really be beneficial for me and others

Comment: Note that this action was deprecated in favor of CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC

Comment: MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER is deprecated!!

Comment: This answer is now obsolete as this action was deprecated. Follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC) to learn how to use Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC.

Answer (score 2):

This works for older versions and you May get **FileUriExposed Exception** due to the security Update in the latest Versions.
To avoid that use the following code

```
 try{
        File file = new File(filepath);
        String mimeType = "audio/*";
        Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                getApplicationContext(),
                getApplicationContext()
                        .getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(fileURI, mimeType);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"-------------------------------------------------------FAILED TO PLAY SONG "+e);
    }
```

Add the Following in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Create a file **provider_paths.xml** under **res/xml/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="."/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are number of way by which you can achieve default audio player but those are device and OS specific.

With this code snippet you can get default audio player.

```
try
    {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File("audiofilepath"); 
    String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
    String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This API is now obsolete.