# Android open default mp3 player within application

Tags: android, mp3, audio-player

Should be really simple.  I just want the default mp3 player to open when a button is pressed as its own activity.  I need it to work on api 3 and higher

This opens a media player but it is not the default:

```
//doesnt open default player
Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   
//File file = new File(objectFilePath);   
viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(null, "audio/*");   
viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
act.startActivity(viewMediaIntent);
```

this doesn't work:(no activity found to handle intent)

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER"); 
act.startActivity(intent);
```

This also works but not for default:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "1"); 
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);   
act.startActivity(it);
```

thank you for your time.

Comment: Try this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027709/androidopen-default-audio-player

This may help you.

Comment: thanks, but I looked at this one before and it didn't work for me.