# How to open a default music player and pass several files to it with an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

When I need to open a file, I just use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114471/android-launching-music-player-using-intent). But what if there are several files (Playlist)? How to pass a list of music files to another application?

Comment: you can look at http://jan.newmarch.name/android/StreamingAudio.html

Comment: May it be something like   mIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM,MediaStore.Audio.Albums.CONTENT_TYPE);