# Play song on default music player - android

Tags: android, android-intent, mediastore, android-music-player

My app show list of song from sd card. I want to be able to play the song on the default player. I've got all the data about the song: id, title, album, artist, path...

Is there a way to launch the default player to play the song?

**What I've tried:**

1. Using `Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC`. I can launch the default player, but can't set the song.
   `Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC)` open the default music app. 
   However`intent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id))` throws exception that intent not found.
2. Using deprecated `MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER`. Activity not found.
   `Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(songFile), "audio/*")`
3. Using `INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH`. Launch the search, but not the song, says couldn't prepare mix on Play music. However, it works from Google now, so it may be the key.
   `Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH).putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, name)`
4. Using `ACTION_VIEW`. it works but it launch a compact version of the player, and I want the full player.

[image: compat view]

**Note:** I want to launch **External player**, not in my app.

**Update**: Looks like Google Now hardcoded Play Music and Youtube support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android launching music player using intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114471/android-launching-music-player-using-intent)

Comment: Actually not, I want to launch specific song, not just music player.

Comment: Did you find the answers>

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to start the default music player app on the device, should try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It launches the compact version of the default music player, see picture in the updated question

Comment: ah, sorry, I miss understand you!

Comment: It is ok, it is the most close solution.

Comment: Hey, I have an idea, but it is very very dark magic Android. You should create a fake launcher icon for your default music player. In this case the OS thinks it should launch the app. Cons of this solution: works for only one player.

Comment: Launching the default media player is easy, but not setting song.

Answer (score 2):

it is launching a compact version for playing as that app has implemented it that way, 
you can find many 3rd party app that open the full app with

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

as you already tried this

Answer (score 0):

Try with something simple like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();     
mp.setLooping(true);
try {
    mp.setDataSource(mFile); //mFile is the path to your mp3 file
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    mp.prepare();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mp.start();
```

And one more example with MadiaPlayer and file saved in res/raw/ directory:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```

More about: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: **Note**: I want to launch **External player**, not in my app.

Comment: Hmmm, so did you try with this selected as best answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114471/android-launching-music-player-using-intent ?

Comment: Yes, it launches a compact version for playing only and not the whole client.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent musicIntent = new Intent();  
 //use Action VIEW to launch app
 musicIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    

String mimeType  = getMimeTypeFromFile(); // in your case it is audio
Uri uri = " yourfile uri";
musicIntent.setDataAndType(uri,mimeType);
startActivity(intent);
```

The default view application will be opened if the mime type is changed, for video mime-type video player will be opened, for audio music player and for image gallery.

If there are multiple player then `Resolver` activity will be opened.

Don’t forget to catch `ActivityNotFoundException`

In Music player for ACTION_VIEW AudioPreview activty is called with  priority. there are other activities which handle this action , just check once with action "`com.android.music.PLAYBACK_VIEWER`" instead of ACTION_VIEW or with it.

Comment: How this is different from solution 4 on my question?

Comment: check AndroidManifest.xl of Music app , you can get the code from AndroidXRef

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.music.PLAYBACK_VIEWER dat=content://media/external/audio/media/2797 typ=audio/* }

Comment: @RahulPatil. would you please answer me?https://stackoverflow.com/q/59809009/4568864