# How To Launch the default Music App in android to play a particular song?

Tags: android, android-intent, audio-player, android-music-player

I want to play a particular song in a url through the default media player

I am able to play it using [Play song on default music player - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937370/play-song-on-default-music-player-android)

but it is not opening the app fully to play it

Also i am able to open the music player with following code

```
Intent intent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);


startActivity(intent);
```

How can i do both ?

Comment: what you mean by "it's not opening the app fully to play it" plz explain.

Comment: it launch a compact version of the player as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937370/play-song-on-default-music-player-android   you can see the screenshot in that post.

Answer (score 1):

Every manufacturer will have its default music player, but if you still want to open default android music player which google provides i.e **Google Play Music** then you can open it with following code:-

This code will open Google Play Music if its installed otherwise it will open some other music player.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Check for Google Play Music exist
    if (isPackageInstalled("com.google.android.music", getPackageManager())) 
    {
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.music");
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    } 
    else
    {
    else
    {
        //Your previous code goes here
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/alarm.mp3");
        if (file!=null)
        {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Music.this,"Sound Track missing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, PackageManager packageManager) 
{
    try 
    {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packagename, 0);
        return true;
    } 
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this may open the default music player .but the actual question is how to play a particular  song in that music player say  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Over the Horizon.mp3");

Comment: it launch a compact version of the player as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937370/play-song-on-default-music-player-android you can see the screenshot in that post.