# how to develop an app for Google home?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I want to develop a music player for Google home, I can't seem to find any resources about that.

Please note that I'm not trying to build a mere action on Google Assistant. I want to build a music player that streams audio, etc. just like when you say "hey Google, play music on Spotify"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Content-based Actions: https://developers.google.com/actions/content-actions/
If you have a podcast then that should be the easiest to integrate.

If you have a media app or service, then deeper integration with the Google Assistant is currently only available for partners: https://developers.google.com/actions/partners/

You can contact the support team if you want to pursue this more.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to build an Action, right? If you want to build a media streamer (like Spotify, Play Music, Soundcloud...) you can develop your Android app and integrate the "media intent" ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114471/android-launching-music-player-using-intent), [link2](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common)).

Comment: but you can only do that for android devices. I don't think  that Google home runs android.